# Improve the performance of retainAll on ArrayList Java 8

Tags: java, performance

I have two data structures (`List<ArrayList<String>>`) as below

```
parentList: [[1, 11], [2, 11], [3, 11], [4, 11]]
childList: [[2, 11], [1, 11], [56], [4, 11], [3, 11], [5, 11], [6], [6]]
```

I want the `childList` to retain all the elements which are present only in `parentList` preserving the order of insertion. i,e:

```
childList: [[2, 11], [1, 11], [4, 11], [3, 11]]
```

The size of the `parentList` is around `500` and that of `childList` is around `50K`. 
I tried:

```
childList.retainAll(parentList);
```

As the size of `childList` increases the time taken by `retainAll` increases drastically.

Using `LinkedHashSet` improves the performance compared to `List` but not up to the expectation.
Is there any other way to fulfill the requirement other than `retainAll` or is there a way to optimize the same operation?

Comment: Can you use `Set`s instead of `List`s or do you need to support duplicates?

Comment: Since I need to preserve the order I can't use set

Comment: `LinkedHashSet`preserves order

Comment: And the order of parentList doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @rmn.nish you can keep the order of insertion in the child and still go over the elements of the parent and add them into a Set. Then go over the child's elements and for each one it'll be O(1) time complexity to check if the element is in the Set. This is a bit simplification since an array is an object it could be that there are two different objects `[2,11]` which means that you'll need to do a bit more work and figure out a good way to hash these elements before inserting into the Set, maybe create a wrapper object which will have a hashcode of an array as its `toString()` for example.